# Jquery AJAX replace with Vanilla js difficulty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Firstly I would like to describe what's wrong.

This is my Jquery code and it's good.

```
 $.ajax({ url: 'ajaxHandler.php',
     data: {'list' : 'list'},
     type: 'post',
     dataType:'json',
     success: function(output) {
                  alert(output);
              },
      error: function(request, status, error){
        alert("Error: Could not delete");
      }
  });
```

But problem is it i have just wanted to create the same in vanilla js.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
          alert(request.responseText);
      };
    }
    var dataParam = {
        'list': 'list'
    };

    var $json = JSON.stringify(dataParam);
    request.send($json);
```

Is Anybody who could tell me where is my mistake.

```
    <?php
    require_once 'tasksController.php';
    $dataFunction =  (string)($_POST['list']);
    echo $dataFunction;

    ?>
```

This is my alert :
Notice: Undefined index: list in C:\xampp..........\ajaxHandler.php  on line 3

Comment: What is the output of `JSON.stringify(dataParam)`? Try `console.log()`'ing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: If you don't need IE11, there's always fetch. http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch and there are polyfills for ie11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery isn't **sending** JSON, it's sending the object as www-urlencoded data, and expecting to get JSON **back**.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data    = new FormData();

data.append('list','list');

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    var result = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    console.log(result);
  }
}

request.open("POST", 'ajaxHandler.php', true);
request.send(data);
```